# Dependednt Drop down list and Different Defined name variations using INDIRECT and SUBSTITUTE

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I have a list of companies, some are multiple words, some are separated by space, others by an "/" and others by "-" . I made a drop down list column that lets me input my choice from the list, then made another drop down list column next to that to select assigned employees names for each company.In a different tab Using "From selection" I made multiple lists with their own defined names , assigning each employee to a company . Problem is that Excel doesn't accept "/", "-" or " " as a list name (characters that appear on my company list ). So in order to create the dependant drop down list of employees to recognize the appropriate list names , I used the following formula in the data validation bar. Its not 100% so I need some assist to finish it ... So far it recognises the company  names separated by space " " but not "-" or "/"... This was written in the employee drop down column in order to make it recognise the company names as they are written normally and not as they appear on the Name Manager.

eg. Cell E1 will say "Lucas-Films", the Name Manager has it as "Lucas_Films", with its assigned employee names, and I want the employee list in F1 to recognise the first form (Lucas-Films) .

```
=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($C624,"- ", "_")," ", "_"))
```

Comment: Show some sample data.

Comment: Maybe `=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($C624;" ";"_");"-";"_");"/";"_")`?